# Function inside for loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I can't grasp the result. I understand the first two sets of output (***func01 1* and *func2 01 - func2 05***). But the rest is confusing.

My understanding is that, after the first execution of the for loop in `func01()`, i gets to 2 and then 3 because of the function `func02()`, but still i <= 3 in `func01()`. I don't know why there isn't ***func01 2 and func01 3*** in the output .

```js
function func02(){
  for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;func02 " + i + "<br>");
  }
}

function func01(){
  for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    document.write("func01 " + i + "<br>");
    func02();
  }
}

func01();
```

Comment: Lookup "Javascript global undeclared variable" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the result I got (formatted)

```
func01 1
func02 1
func02 2
func02 3
func02 4
func02 5
```

`func01` is called, sets i (which is global variable) to 1, and prints a line
Then `func01` calls `func02`
`func02` resets i to 1, and then prints a line for each `i=1,2,3,4,5`.
Then control returns to `func01`.  It has completed the first loop iteration.  The value of i is 5.  It then compares i (as its global variable) to 3.  Seeing that 5 is greater, the loop is over.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a variable without using `var`, and it doesn't exist anywhere in the current scope, it's looked for in the next scope up. If it's not there, the next scope up is checked, etc.

If the variable is not found in *any* scope, it gets assigned to the global scope. So both `func01` and `func01` are referring to and updating the same `i` variable. So `func02` runs, loops, and finishes. Then by the time it gets to `func01`, `i` is `6` and the loop doesn't run again in `func0`.

You can get the expected result if you change the counters to use `var`. That will scope `i` to the functions they're inside of.

```js
function func02(){
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;func02 " + i + "<br>");
  }
}

function func01(){
  for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    document.write("func01 " + i + "<br>");
    func02();
  }
}

func01();
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `i` as a local scopes variable, so it's being created as a global variable. Use `let` or `var`:

```js
 

function func02(){
  for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;func02 " + i + "<br>");
  }
}

function func01(){
  for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
document.write("func01 " + i + "<br>");
func02();
  }
}

func01();
```

Answer (score 0):

[user202729](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5267751/user202729) is right. In javascript, if you do not declare a variable, it takes global scope, instead of taking the function's scope in which that variable is used.

Declare your *variable i*, as follows ,

```
for(var i = 1;i <= 5 ; i++)
```

or you can declare the variable at the beginning of the function like,

```
var i;
```

```js
function func02(){

  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;func02 " + i + "<br>");
  }
}

function func01(){
  for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    document.write("func01 " + i + "<br>");
    func02();
  }
}

func01();
```

Do refer https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp and lookup about the scoping of javascript variables.